# .htaccess HTTPS redirect with exceptions

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, https

I am looking for a .htaccess code to redirect HTTPS requests on a certain url/page to HTTP (without SSL, yes the otherway around).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable `mod_rewrite` and `.htaccess` through `httpd.conf` (if not already enabled) and then put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^surf\.php$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: added this code

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule ^(surf\.php)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]